# DDD: Domain Driven Design. What does the Domain mean in DDD?

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design

What exactly does the word domain mean in DDD?  I keep reading the definition... and although i see things like the domain model and understand what model is - what does domain model mean?

What does domain actually mean?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Domain* refers to the topic your application addresses.

For example, if you are writing an online store, the Domain is *online retailing*, and the Domain Model is that part of the application that deals with the business logic of *online retailing* - as opposed to rendering UI, accessing databases, etc.

Comment: thanks alot!! now its clear....  its been annoying me for a while! Thanks for a great explanation